# Delete an item of a computed list in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I would need to display a list of items, and be able to erase one of them when needed.

```
  <tr v-for="(todo, key, index) in todo_list">
    <td><input v-model.trim="todo.priority" type="number"/></td>
    <td><a v-on:click="todo_list.splice(index, 1)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
```

The problem here is the fact that todo_list is computed. Thanks to the v-model, I can edit the priority. I can notice that edit. But I want to be able to delete any item too. It doesn't trigger any error or warning (vue.js file non-minified).

I tried `Vue.delete(todo_list, index)`, I tried to pass key instead of index, to do it in a method. None of that worked. Note: when I tried the method, I entered in it: I could log in the console before and after the `splice`.

I can create an attribute in data that would mirror that computed value, but I believe it would be useless code. Is there a way to to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to delete the item from the original object that the computed is made from, or just tell the computed not to include it?

Comment: Hello Roy! I would like to delete it from the original object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each todo has a unique `key`, just use these key to delete from original data.

a todo:

```
{
  key: 0,
  priority: 5,
  ...
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/LxjLoE?editors=1010

```
v-on:click="() => remove(todo.key)"
```

and the remove method:

```
remove (key) {
    this.todoList = this.todoList.filter(todo => todo.key !== key)
}
```